# Why is using %do% loop is using multiple processors? Expected sequential loop

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I'm using foreach and reading up on it e.g.

- https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/foreach/versions/1.4.3/topics/foreach

My understanding is that you would use `%dopar%` for parallel processing and `%do%` for sequential.

As it happens I was having issues with `%dopar%` and while trying to debug I changed it to a what I thought was a sequential loop using `%do%`. I happened to have the terminal open and noticed all processors running while I ran the loop.

Is this expected?

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(foreach)

# expected to see parallel here because caret and xgb with train()
xgbFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "xgbTree", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE))

iris_big <- do.call(rbind, replicate(1000, iris, simplify = F))

nr <- nrow(iris_big)
n <- 1000 # loop over in chunks of 20
pieces <- split(iris_big, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr))
lenp <- length(pieces)

# did not expect to see parallel processing take place when running the block below
predictions <- foreach(i = seq_len(lenp)) %do% {

  # get prediction
  preds <- pieces[[i]] %>% 
    mutate(xgb_prediction = predict(xgbFit, newdata = .))

  return(preds)
}

bah <- do.call(rbind, predictions)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be that these are processes still running from previous runs.

It is the same when using `foreach::registerDoSeq()`?

My second guess would be that `predict` runs in parallel.

Comment: Looks like it's your second guess and that this is not to do with foreach. I ran predict on iris_big not in a loop and saw parallel processing take place there too. However, only with xgb model. When I change to a e.g. knn model no parallel prediction. Odd since I'd expect parallel could be used with predicting with any model. I'll add caret tag or maybe post another question on why predict uses parallel only with XGB

Comment: @DougFir This is really interesting. I would like to know how to force `predict` to run sequentially as it can mess up with some higher level parallelism that I use in my code.

Comment: Over here for interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153342/why-does-caretpredict-use-parallel-processing-with-xgbtree-only